# Concatenate multiple values from a column based on substrings from a single string on another column

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have an Oracle table with the following columns and strings:

```
| Name    |   Id     |   Path    |
|---------+----------+-----------|
| Base1   | B1       | /B1       |
| Mid1    | M1       | /B1/M1    |
| Top1    | T1       | /B1/M2/T1 |
| Mid2    | M2       | /B1/M2    |
| Top2    | T2       | /B2/M1/T2 |
| Top3    | T3       | /B2/M1/T3 |
| Base2   | B2       | /B2       |
```

I need to display the paths with names instead of Id's. Desired outcome:

```
Base1
Base1/Mid2
Base1/Mid2/Top1
Base1/Mid2
Base2/Mid1/Top2
Base2/Mid1/Top3
Base2
```

I can grab and concatenate the individual substrings with `regexp_substr(path, '[^/]+', 1, 1)` and use `REPLACE(regexp_substr(path, '[^/]+', 1, 1),id,name)` to replace a corresponding substring within the full string but how do I get the names for the substrings that do not have a corresponding Id on the same row?

Comment: Your data does not quite work as `M1` has `B1` as its parent but in `T2` and `T3` it has `B2` as its parent.

Comment: That relation is not relevant in this case. Only getting values from another column to replace substrings of a single string.

Answer (score 1):

You have hierarchical data; its much easier to solve the problem if you turn the paths back the connections to the previous level of the hierarchy (by finding the previous level of the path) and then you can rebuild the path using a hierarchical query:

```sql
SELECT name,
       id,
       path,
       SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(name, '/') AS name_path
FROM   (
  SELECT name,
         id,
         path, 
         SUBSTR(path, INSTR(path, '/', -1, 2) + 1, INSTR(path, '/', -1, 1) - INSTR(path, '/', -1, 2) - 1) AS prev
  FROM   table_name
)
START WITH prev IS NULL
CONNECT BY PRIOR id = prev;
```

or:

```sql
SELECT name,
       id,
       path,
       SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(name, '/') AS name_path
FROM   (
  SELECT name,
         id,
         path,
         SUBSTR(path, 1, INSTR(path, '/', -1, 1) - 1) AS prev
  FROM   table_name
)
START WITH prev IS NULL
CONNECT BY PRIOR path = prev
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( Name, Id, Path ) AS
SELECT 'Base1', 'B1', '/B1'       FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Mid1',  'M1', '/B2/M1'    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Top1',  'T1', '/B1/M2/T1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Mid2',  'M2', '/B1/M2'    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Top2',  'T2', '/B2/M1/T2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Top3',  'T3', '/B2/M1/T3' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Base2', 'B2', '/B2'       FROM DUAL;
```

*Note: I have fixed the data so the path goes `/B2` then `/B2/M1/` then `/B2/M1/T2` rather than randomly changing from `B1` to `B2` part-way through the path.*

Both output:

| NAME | ID | PATH | NAME_PATH |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Base1 | B1 | /B1 | /Base1 |
| Mid2 | M2 | /B1/M2 | /Base1/Mid2 |
| Top1 | T1 | /B1/M2/T1 | /Base1/Mid2/Top1 |
| Base2 | B2 | /B2 | /Base2 |
| Mid1 | M1 | /B2/M1 | /Base2/Mid1 |
| Top2 | T2 | /B2/M1/T2 | /Base2/Mid1/Top2 |
| Top3 | T3 | /B2/M1/T3 | /Base2/Mid1/Top3 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/RGpNJfcr)

Comment: @MTO Fiddle results with 5 rows not 7 as stated in the answer!?

Comment: @dr I'd changed the algorithm and not spotted that it had highlighted a problem with the OP's data set (`M1` changes from having `B1` to `B2` as a parent) and when you fix the data so that it is internally consistent then the problem goes away.

Comment: Yes, the consistency of the elements of the path is not relevant in this scenario. My apologies for omitting that information.

Answer (score 1):

One of the options could be:

```sql
SELECT
    (Select A_NAME From tbl Where ID = t.E_1) || 
        CASE WHEN t.ELEMENTS > 1 THEN '/' || (Select A_NAME From tbl Where ID = t.E_2) END || 
        CASE WHEN t.ELEMENTS > 2 THEN '/' || (Select A_NAME From tbl Where ID = t.E_3) END || 
        CASE WHEN t.ELEMENTS > 3 THEN '/' || (Select A_NAME From tbl Where ID = t.E_4) END "TXT"
FROM 
    ( Select    t.A_NAME, t.ID, t.A_PATH, 
                Length(t.A_PATH) - Length(Replace(A_PATH, '/', '')) "ELEMENTS",
                SubStr(A_PATH, InStr(t.A_PATH, '/', 1, 1) + 1, 2) "E_1",
                SubStr(A_PATH, CASE WHEN InStr(t.A_PATH, '/', 1, 2) != 0 THEN InStr(t.A_PATH, '/', 1, 2) + 1 END, 2) "E_2",
                SubStr(A_PATH, CASE WHEN InStr(t.A_PATH, '/', 1, 3) != 0 THEN InStr(t.A_PATH, '/', 1, 3) + 1 END, 2) "E_3",
                SubStr(A_PATH, CASE WHEN InStr(t.A_PATH, '/', 1, 4) != 0 THEN InStr(t.A_PATH, '/', 1, 4) + 1 END, 2) "E_4"
      From      tbl t
    ) t
```

which withh your sample data:

```sql
WITH
    tbl(A_NAME, ID, A_PATH) AS 
        (
            Select 'Base1', 'B1', '/B1' From Dual Union All
            Select 'Mid1', 'M1', '/B1/M1' From Dual Union All
            Select 'Top1', 'T1', '/B1/M2/T1' From Dual Union All
            Select 'Mid2', 'M2', '/B1/M2' From Dual Union All
            Select 'Top2', 'T2', '/B2/M1/T2' From Dual Union All
            Select 'Top3', 'T3', '/B2/M1/T3' From Dual Union All
            Select 'Base2', 'B2', '/B2' From Dual 
        )
```

... results with:

```sql
TXT             
-----------------
Base1             
Base1/Mid1        
Base1/Mid2/Top1   
Base1/Mid2        
Base2/Mid1/Top2   
Base2/Mid1/Top3   
Base2
```

And another option resulting the same is to use [MODEL](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/10g/r2/prod/bidw/sqlmodel/sqlmodel_otn.htm) like below:

```sql
SELECT    TXT
FROM    (   Select  A_NAME, ID, A_PATH, CAST('xxx' as VarChar2(50)) "TXT"
            From    tbl  )
        MODEL Dimension By (ID)
              Measures(A_NAME, A_PATH, TXT)
              Rules ( 
                      TXT[ANY] = CASE WHEN Length(A_PATH[CV()]) = 3 THEN A_NAME[SubStr(A_PATH[CV()], 2, 2)] 
                                      WHEN Length(A_PATH[CV()]) = 6 THEN A_NAME[SubStr(A_PATH[CV()], 2, 2)] || '/' || A_NAME[SubStr(A_PATH[CV()], 5, 2)] 
                                      WHEN Length(A_PATH[CV()]) = 9 THEN A_NAME[SubStr(A_PATH[CV()], 2, 2)] || '/' || A_NAME[SubStr(A_PATH[CV()], 5, 2)]|| '/' || A_NAME[SubStr(A_PATH[CV()], 8, 2)]
                                  END
                    )
```

**Addition** (ccomented scenario)

```sql
-- Scenario_2:  different origins of data
-- TBL - cte named "tbl" containes ID and A_NAME columns
-- it is irrelevant where are they from as long as you have or could have unique ID's
WITH
    tbl(A_NAME, ID) AS 
        (
          Select 'Base1', 'B1'  From Dual Union All
          Select 'Mid1',  'M1'  From Dual Union All
          Select 'Top1',  'T1'  From Dual Union All
          Select 'Mid2',  'M2'  From Dual Union All
          Select 'Top2',  'T2'  From Dual Union All
          Select 'Top3',  'T3'  From Dual Union All
          Select 'Base2', 'B2'  From Dual 
        ),
-- PATHS - origin also irrelevant - there could be as many paths as you want
-- they don't have to be unique but should be consisted of IDs existing in the previous cte(tbl)
    tbl_or_view_or_cte_paths (A_PATH) AS
        (
          Select '/B1'        From Dual Union All
          Select '/B1/M1'     From Dual Union All
          Select '/B1/M2/T1'  From Dual Union All
          Select '/B1/M2'     From Dual Union All
          Select '/B2/M1/T2'  From Dual Union All
          Select '/B2/M1/T3'  From Dual Union All
          Select '/B2'        From Dual Union All
          --  some extra random paths below
          Select '/B1/M1/T1'     From Dual Union All
          Select '/B2/M2/T2'  From Dual Union All
          Select '/B2/M2/T3'  From Dual Union All
          Select '/M1/T1/T2/T3'  From Dual   -- one path with 4 elements
        )
SELECT
    (Select A_NAME From tbl Where ID = t.E_1) || 
        CASE WHEN t.ELEMENTS > 1 THEN '/' || (Select A_NAME From tbl Where ID = t.E_2) END || 
        CASE WHEN t.ELEMENTS > 2 THEN '/' || (Select A_NAME From tbl Where ID = t.E_3) END || 
        CASE WHEN t.ELEMENTS > 3 THEN '/' || (Select A_NAME From tbl Where ID = t.E_4) END "TXT"
FROM 
    ( Select    Length(t.A_PATH) - Length(Replace(A_PATH, '/', '')) "ELEMENTS",
                SubStr(A_PATH, InStr(t.A_PATH, '/', 1, 1) + 1, 2) "E_1",
                SubStr(A_PATH, CASE WHEN InStr(t.A_PATH, '/', 1, 2) != 0 THEN InStr(t.A_PATH, '/', 1, 2) + 1 END, 2) "E_2",
                SubStr(A_PATH, CASE WHEN InStr(t.A_PATH, '/', 1, 3) != 0 THEN InStr(t.A_PATH, '/', 1, 3) + 1 END, 2) "E_3",
                SubStr(A_PATH, CASE WHEN InStr(t.A_PATH, '/', 1, 4) != 0 THEN InStr(t.A_PATH, '/', 1, 4) + 1 END, 2) "E_4"
      From      tbl_or_view_or_cte_paths t
    ) t

TXT                   
-----------------------
Base1                   
Base1/Mid1              
Base1/Mid2/Top1         
Base1/Mid2              
Base2/Mid1/Top2         
Base2/Mid1/Top3         
Base2                   
Base1/Mid1/Top1         
Base2/Mid2/Top2         
Base2/Mid2/Top3         
Mid1/Top1/Top2/Top3
```

Comment: This does not spot that the OP's data is internally inconsistent as `M1` has the path `/B1/M1` but when you reference it for `T2` then the path does not match as it is `/B2/M1`. It is unclear whether `M1` should be matched in this case as the `ID` matches but the path doesn't.

Comment: @MT0 Yes, the consistency could be an issue, but we don't know why it is like that (could be intentional too, it's not on me to do the judging) and, as I see it, the ID is ID and the code should work even if the path is /M1/M1/M1 resulting with Mid1/Mid1/Mid1...

Comment: Yes, the consistency of the elements of the path is not relevant in this case. My apologies for omitting that information. What I also failed to mention is that the path is originally selected as is from a joined table (t2.path) as part of a longer query. Can I make these fit into that type of scenario?

Comment: @day1 In the 1st option important thing is that you have unique ID (either in any table or view or cte). The origin of path is irrelevant - after getting the elements the TXT is concatinated using Selects where ID = Element. In the 2nd option it could be done too adjusting the data passed to a model to be as it is now.

Comment: @day1 Just posted the Addition that gets data from different sources. Comments in code.